# Macro "trigger on cell change" is also triggered when inserting rows

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently using VBA to check when cells in a certain column are changed, so I can call a different macro to sort them. This works wonderfully, except that it also triggers whenever I insert a new row. So using IsEmpty I added a check to see if the cell in question isn't empty. But I'm obviously doing it wrong, since my macro is still called whenever I insert a row. What am I doing wrong?

The VBA that triggers on cell changes:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range

    Set KeyCells = Range("A:A")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

        If Not IsEmpty(KeyCells) Then
            Call SortByDate
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't check an array using `IsEmpty`. You need to loop through the cells in `Intersect(KeyCells, Target)` because more than one row could be inserted at once.

Comment: ① you might filter out row insertions with `if target.count >= columns.count then exit sub` ② If you are changing anything on that worksheet use `application.enableevents = false` before starting to change anything and `application.enableevents = true` before leaving the sub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might filter out row insertions by checking the number of cells that received a change. In the case of a row insertion, this is greater than or equal to the worksheet's `columns.count`. If you are changing anything on that worksheet use `application.enableevents = false` before starting to change anything and `application.enableevents = true` before leaving the sub.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' exit immediately on row insertion
    If Target.CountLarge >= Columns.Count Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Columns(1)) Is Nothing Then
        'escape route
        On Error GoTo bm_Safe_Exit

        'don't declare or Set anything until you know you will need it
        '(this isn't really terribly necessary)
        Dim KeyCells As Range
        Set KeyCells = Range("A:A")

        If Application.CountA(KeyCells) Then 'is there ANYTHING in A:A?
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Call SortByDate
        End If

    End If
bm_Safe_Exit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Failing to disable event handling and subsequently changing anything on the worksheet will trigger another change event and the [Worksheet_Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event macro will try to run on top of itself.

Comment: Just to be clear - you seem to believe that **Target** is a single cell when you insert a row. It is not. Target is a range of cells that encompasses the entire row that was inserted. In the case of an XLSX worksheet, this is 16,384 cells when inserting a single row.

Comment: Just in case the user does something that changes a larger number of cells than a `Long` can hold (2,147,483,647; this is possible in newer versions of Excel but probably  a bad idea), it may be safer to use `Target.CountLarge` in the initial check.

Comment: They would have to insert or delete over 2,000 entire columns but your your point is very valid and well taken. I'll edit to suit above.

Comment: `If Target.CountLarge >= Columns.Count Then Exit Sub` - wouldn't this also exit if the user pastes in more than ~16k values into a column ? Maybe `If Target.Areas(1).Columns.Count = Columns.Count Then Exit Sub` ?

Comment: @TimWilliams - Yes it would. The work-around would be to select a single cell, tap F2 then Enter after the Worksheet_Change rejected the large worksheet modification.